# ML.Net code for Linux machine - MklImports: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, nuget, ml.net, dotnet-cli

I need to create a class library project that uses ML.Net and it needs to be intefrated with an external application. This code needs to be running on Linux machine. I am on windows machine and everything works fine. I create the publish package using the following command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained false
```

When I provide this package to the third party application, and one of the methods inside the assembly gets called, they get the following error:

> Unable to load shared library MklImports or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: MklImports: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Upon further investigation it is found that the root cause is that libMklImports depends on OpenMP library libiomp5. Because of redistribution licensing reasons, libiomp5.dll is packaged in the ML.NET nugets for Windows only. libiomp5.dylib and libiomp5.so are not packaged for MacOS and Linux, respectively. If these libraries are not already present on the system, this error will be thrown.

So my question is how can I include these missing libraries when I create a publish package for Linux from Windows machine?

One workaround is to include the libraries using the target Linux machine which I do not really want. I would prefer these required libraries to be included from my environment in the release package as we will be having multiple POCs on different environments. Including these assemblies on each and every Linux machine will not be a good solution.

The code is expected to work on Linux machine as it is working on Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort this by just adding the Nuget package **MKL.NET.linux-x64** to your project before publishing.